# Returning a value from a segmented control

Tags: swift, return-value, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to return a value when a user selects one of the segmented control options. I am getting the error

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function.

How can I get `pageStatus` to change to what is clicked by the user?

```
class ReportsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var reportList:[String] = []

var ref: DatabaseReference!

var handle: DatabaseHandle?

var pageStatus = "default"


@IBOutlet weak var reportsTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "reportsToHome", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func segmentControlPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        pageStatus = "unclaimed";
    case 1:
        pageStatus = "complete";
    case 2:
        pageStatus = "cancelled";
    default:
        break;
    }
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return reportList.count

}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = reportList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    handle = ref.child("Reports").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let reports = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                let firstName = reports["firstName"] as? String
                let lastName = reports["lastName"] as? String
                let user = reports["user"] as? String
                let status = reports["status"] as? String
                let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


                if user == userID && status == self.pageStatus{
                    self.reportList.append(firstName! + " " + lastName!)
                    self.reportsTableView.reloadData()

                }
                else{
                    print(status ?? "page status" + self.pageStatus);
                }
            }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that all IBActions *always* have no return.

You have many options, two of which are:

- If you are using `pageStatus` in the same view controller, just set the value and call a function that uses an instance variable called `pageStatus`.
- If you are using `pageStatus in another view controller, set that value in the view controller using it and either segue to it or present it.

Comment: I am using it in the same view controller. How would I set an instance variable based on what segmented control the user has selected?

Comment: Making an edit. Basically, just expose the segmented control.

Comment: sorry, I am a novice at this. What do you mean by expose the segmented control?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return anything in your IBAction, just change "let" to "var" to make pageStatus mutable and set it in your function:

```
var pageStatus = "default"

@IBAction func segmentControlPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
       pageStatus = "unclaimed";
    case 1:
       pageStatus = "complete";
    case 2:
       pageStatus = "cancelled";
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that, I do not get an error, but the correct content does not display. I don't think that it is updating pageStatus outside that function in the rest of the view controller

Comment: @Bob I'm 100% sure that this code is updating pageStatus. Show how you are displaying your content.

Comment: see my edit above. I put in print(status ?? "page status" + self.pageStatus); to test. This was the output: page statusdefault
page statusdefault
page statusdefault
page statusdefault
page statusdefault
unclaimed
unclaimed
unclaimed
unclaimed
unclaimed
unclaimed
unclaimed

Answer (score 0):

make sure your IBAction is connected as ValueChanged not as TouchUpInside

Comment: It is value changed